# Is this a right attribute?: C:\>attrib +s +h d:\example\sample

Tags: windows-10

The directory is just an example.

I want the parent folder and all of the files inside it to be unsearchable... but I'm not sure of that attribute that will be enter to the command prompt

Answer (score 2):

What does unsearchable mean?

The command you listed will indeed make the directory hidden. But, that only means it will be made hidden from File Explorer. It can easily be found.

If you don't want Windows Search to index it, you will need to explicitly block that directory from being indexed in the Windows Search settings.

You can use NTFS permissions to limit access to that directory. That will prevent other users from being able to access its contents. But, if the drive is removed and put into another computer, the contents can be viewed.

If you want to protect it so no one can view the contents of the directory, you need to encrypt it. I suggest using BitLocker since it is secure, super simple to use, built-in to Windows, and automatically unlocks it via your user account.